# Domino Agent issues when running in Notes Client - works fine on server

Tags: java, security, xpages, lotus-domino, agent

I have a java agent that makes http requests using jsoup, This agent works fine when I trigger it manually from the server console. but will give an error when I run it on the client, (right click on agent and run)

- The agent is set to option 2. Allow restricted operations, and is set to "Action menu selection" and Target "All documents in database"
- I have set the same security settings in my java.policy file on both the server and the client.
  I also tried to run my agent on a server with a "standard" java.policy file and that worked also so the problem do not seem to be related to the java.policy file.

This is the error I get in the Java debug console when I run the agent in notes client (v9.0.1)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:727)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:654)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:411)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:703)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:399)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:453)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is the java.policy settings I use in my Notes client (and on some servers)

> grant { permission java.util.PropertyPermission "http.keepAlive",
>   "read, write"; };
>
> grant { permission java.security.AllPermission;  }

Here is the agent code

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

public void NotesMain() {

  try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
      Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
      lotus.domino.Document d = db.getView("inbox").getFirstDocument();

      String url = d.getItemValueString("Subject"); 
      Document x = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
      Elements p = x.select("p");
      RichTextItem rt = (RichTextItem) d.getFirstItem("Body");
      rt.appendText(p.text());
      d.replaceItemValue("Processed", "1");
      d.save();

  } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}
}

How can I get the agent to run on my local Notes client?

Comment: I know that not all libraries that is on the server is available from the client. My webservice hack with XPages works from the server but not the client

Comment: Can you check if the response is OK (using .method and .response instead of .get()). Seems like it does not have a valid response while it has a response code. Sometimes it's a proxy problem, it returns 302 and no response (Are you behind a proxy?)

Comment: thanks Serdar, there is no proxy in my network. I am not sure how to get the response, all I get it org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response@13491349

Comment: Does the local machine have a firewall or any security software installed that might be interfering with the agent's ability to connect? Have you tried using the java.net.HttpUrlConnection class directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this: [Java Agent HTTP Connection Errors](http://www.nsftools.com/blog/blog-01-2015.htm#01-15-155)
This solved the problem for me.

> After many restarts and toggled settings, and much pulling of hair, I was able to find a set of steps that would either cause the problem or prevent it. To make the code work:
>
> 1. Open the Notes client
> 2. Run the Java agent
> 3. HTTP connection works
>
> To get the error:
>
> 4. Open the Notes client
> 5. Open the Java Debug Console
> 6. Run the Java agent
> 7. HTTP connection fails
>
> There's something about opening the Java Debug Console before running the agent that causes Notes to use a COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection to make the connection instead of a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection, and the JEmpower version of the class is the one that's broken (per experimentation and the APAR mentioned previously).
>
> Oddly, **if I run the agent and then open the debug console and then run the agent again, everything is fine**. It's opening the debug console before I do anything that causes problems.

Comment: That seems to be a description of a problem and a workaround, rather than a programatic fix for the issue described in the original question

Comment: @beresfordt The question presents the symptom. And I found this question because of the symptoms I also had, unaware of this UI behaviour, thus leading me to a solution. This also appears to be the only solution available. The answer does not have to be programmatic in all cases. The issue is a UI problem in the Domino Designer, and IBM must release a fix to address the issue.